# Highcharts with React - categories showing as numbers instead of text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I'm implementing the highcharts-react bundle (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react) in my Laravel project and I need to be able to retrieve data from my reducer and insert it into a string to place into the categories in the chart config.

However, even though the data appears to be rendering correctly (as per the console logging) the chart categories simply render as numbers from 0 to 4.

Here is my React code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.refreshServiceProviders(); // this pulls in the data
}

const { providers } = this.props;
const spArray = [];

// build up the array of Service Providers
{ providers.map(function (provider) {
    spArray[provider.id] = provider.name;
}, this)}

// remove empty values
const newArray = spArray.filter(function(x){
    return (x !== (undefined || null || ''));
});

// join the values by comma, encased in quotes
const spList = "['" + newArray.join("','") + "']";
```

And then in my Highchart config under the X-axis, I pass the `spList` constant:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: { spList }
```

When I console log out the spList, I get the following:

```
'Provider 1', 'Provider 2', 'Provider 3', 'Provider 4', 'Provider 5'
```

which when passed directly in the categories option in the config works perfectly - but for some reason doesn't work when passing it via the constant.

Is there something I've missed here? I'm not sure what to do.
    },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `categories` object wrong.

When you do `categories: { spList }` what JavaScript actually does is create the following object:

```
categories: {
    spList: '[...]'
}
```

Also, you don't need to join the string in `spList` because `newArray` is already an array.

So basically what you need to do is set your `categories` like `categories: newArray`.

Comment: Actually I though the original issue was that it wasn't split into a string - I'm quite new to React so I wasn't sure of the format I needed to use but I get it now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try doing `categories: spList` instead of `categories: { spList }`. That is, remove the `{}` which denotes an Object instead of an Array.